# C Structure: member order and memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, structure, member

Instead of writing a structure like,

```
typedef struct {
    uint8 len;          // Command length (cmd ... crc)
    uint8 cmd;          // Command code
    uint8 data_length;  // Data length
    uint8 data[12];     // Data: max 12 Byte
    uint8 crc_h;        // CRC value MSB
    uint8 crc_l;        // CRC value LSB
}CMD_TYPE;
```

can I write it like this ?

```
typedef struct { uint8 len, cmd, data_length, data[12], crc_h, crc_l; }CMD_TYPE;
```

If it is possible then why aren't people grouping similar members?!
what would happen to the memory allocation scheme, also is there any hidden side effects to changing the order of members other than memory loss(due to padding if i am right!).

Pardon me if this seems so silly.

Comment: Where would you put the comments then?

Comment: You would save even more typing with `typedef struct{uint8 x[17];}c;`. Why don't people do that?

Comment: Hello Bo you are not helping and what is that attitude?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write both ways, but you'll notice that the first way is more readable than the second one, and since data structures are very important in *C* it is in practice preferable to define them in a more verbose way.

The way you write your `struct` declaration (in one line per field, or every fields of the same type on the same line) don't inpact what happens at runtime.

The order of member fields inside `struct` is very important.

Padding, or the `sizeof` of your `struct`, or its alignment depend only of fields and their order (and of the target processor and ABI), not of the way you write them.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the help. But I am very doubtful about about your last comment, cause the sizeof the following two structure differ drastically. <br/>Structure1:<br/> struct test{<br/>char a; <br/>int b;<br/> char c;<br/>}<br/>struct test1{<br/>char a,c;<br/>int b;<br/>}

Comment: So Please consider revising the post

Comment: I did say that the order of member fields is important. I improved my post: the order of member fields may influence the size of the `struct`

Answer (score 1):

> why aren't people grouping similar members?!

Structs are what group similar members. Declaring multiple variables per line is only good when they are strongly related, such as:

```
int width, height;
char *begin, *end;
```

Or when you need multiple variables declared in a `for` loop.

Note that separate lines is much easier to read. Humans read well in short, aligned columns (2-dimensional) rather than long lines (1-dimensional).

> what would happen to the memory allocation scheme, also is there any hidden side effects to changing the order of members otherthan memory loss(due to padding if i am right!).

Nothing that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing your code works is that you have the same type (unsigned byte).

This is not the case most often + it's always nice to have comments above or at the right of each member.

Answer (score 0):

Here you would get to see what the standard says about padding and memory allocation.
![This is directly from ISO C Standard DOC][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzgDY.png